# How to get the child count of parent having dynamic id in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a dropdown and few divs,once you change the dropdown, divs will create based on json and selection.Here every thing is fine here,but I need to get count of childs(here p tags ) of each parent(here div tags ) ,here once you select technology,you can see there are 2 childs under python so it should be 2 just beside python..so on.Here is the code and updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XEzYi1JEeOtvqC6xn9jZ?p=preview).

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select class="change" ng-model="x" ng-change="update()">
<option value="technology">technology</option>
<option value="vertical">vertical</option>
</select>

<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: attr" ng-attr-id="{{key}}">
  <h4>Group name: {{ key }}</h4>
  <p ng-repeat="player in value">
    player: {{ player.name }} 
  </p>
</div>

</div>
```

### script.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['angular.filter']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.players = [
    {
      name: 'projectjava',
      symptom:'fever',
      technology:'java',
       vertical:'insurance',      
      id:'1'
    },

    {
      name: 'projecttabulue',
      symptom:'diesease',
      technology:'tabulue',
       vertical:'Banking',    
      id:'3'
    },
    {
      name: 'projectpython1',
      symptom:'diesease',
      technology:'python',
       vertical:'Health care',    
      id:'3'
    },
    {
     name: 'projectpython2',
      symptom:'colds',
      technology:'python',
       vertical:'Banking',    
      id:'2'
    }

    ];

     $scope.update = function() {      
  if($scope.x == 'technology'){
   $scope.id='technology';
    $scope.attr = 'technology'; 


   }
   if($scope.x == 'vertical'){
   $scope.id='vertical';
   $scope.attr = 'vertical';    
   }
   }
});
```

Comment: what is the issue with current output

Comment: once selected the select, do you want the number of the projects in the categories, or the number of the categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `value.length` to display the count of the elements.

like this,

```
<h4>Group name: {{ key }} {{value.length}}</h4>
```

Here is the [demo](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/yJPCCqADPsUuPbtu)